# find if string starts with \U in Python 3.3

Tags: regex, string, python-3.3

I have a string and I want to find out if it starts with `\U`.
Here is an example

```
myStr = '\U0001f64c\U0001f60d\U0001f4a6\U0001f445\U0001f4af'
```

I was trying this:

```
myStr.startswith('\\U')
```

but I get `False`.

How can I detect `\U` in a string?

The larger picture:

I have a list of strings, most of them are normal English word strings, but there are a few that are similar to what I have shown in `myStr`, how can I distinguish them?

Comment: Returns `True` on my end..

Comment: The ``\u`` signifies a Unicode codepoint, not two literal ``\`` ``u`` characters. Your question is thus a bit meaningless, since every character can be expressed that way, from ``A`` to ``☺`` (white smiling face). I'd suggest taking a look at the [Python Unicode Howto](https://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: In other words, think about what you want to actually achieve with that ``myStr.startswith(...)`` line in your code. If you're still unclear, ask a new question (including some more information about what your overall goal is).

Comment: @ChristianAichinger ok, how can I find out if the string starts with a Unicode codepoint?

Comment: Please take 5 minutes to read the Unicode Howto I quoted above. Every character is a Unicode codepoint. So unless you have an empty string, the answer is always ``True``.

Comment: @ChristianAichinger thanks for your help. I have a list of strings, most of them are normal English word strings, but there are a few that  are similar to what I have shown in `myStr`, how can I distinguish them?

Comment: @TJ1, If you are in Python 3, even normal English strings will have a `\U` representation.

Comment: @TJ1, See my second update for another heuristic for detecting "normal" ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string:

```
myStr = '\U0001f64c\U0001f60d\U0001f4a6\U0001f445\U0001f4af'
```

is not a foraign language text. It is 5 Unicode characters, which are (in order):

- [PERSON RAISING BOTH HANDS IN CELEBRATION](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f64c/index.htm)
- [SMILING FACE WITH HEART-SHAPED EYES](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f60d/index.htm)
- [SPLASHING SWEAT SYMBOL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a6/index.htm)
- [TONGUE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f445/index.htm)
- [HUNDRED POINTS SYMBOL](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4af/index.htm)

If you want to get strings that only contain 'normal' characters, you can use something like this:

```
if re.search(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\s]', myStr):
    # String contained 'weird' characters.
```

Note that this will also trip on characters like `é`, which will sometimes be used in English on words with a French origin.

Comment: Thanks, should we change it to `if re.search(r'[A-Za-z0-9\s]', myStr):` for `normal` characters?

Comment: ``re.search(r'[A-Za-z0-9\s]', ...`` matches as soon as there is *any* 'normal' character in the string. This may not be what you want. If you want to look for strings that contain *only* 'normal' characters, I'd go with ``not re.search(r'[^A-Za-z0-9\s]', myStr)``.

Answer (score 3):

The original string does not have the character `\U`. It has the unicode escape sequence `\U0001f64c`, which is a single Unicode character.

Therefore, it does not make sense to try to detect `\U` in the string you have given.

Trying to detect the `\U` in that string is similar to trying to detect `\x` in the C string `"\x90"`.

It makes no sense because the interpreter has read the sequence and converted it. Of course, if you want to detect the first Unicode character in that string, that works fine.

```
myStr.startswith('\U0001f64c')
```

Note that if you define the string with a real `\U`, like this, you can detect it just fine. Based on some experimentation, I believe `Python 2.7.6` defaults to this behavior.

```
myStr = r'\U0001f64c\U0001f60d\U0001f4a6\U0001f445\U0001f4af'
myStr.startswith('\\U') # Returns True.
```

**Update**: The OP requested a way to convert from the Unicode string into the raw string above.
I will show the solution in two steps.

First observe that we can view the raw hex for each character like this.

```
>>> [hex(ord(x)) for x in myStr]
['0x1f64c', '0x1f60d', '0x1f4a6', '0x1f445', '0x1f4af']
```

Next, we format it by using a format string.

```
formatString = "".join(r'\U%08x' for x in myStr)
output = formatString % tuple(myChars)
output.startswith("\\U") # Returns True.
```

Note of course that since we are converting a Unicode string and we are formatting it this way deliberately, it guaranteed to start with `\U`. However, I assume your actual application is not just to detect whether it starts with `\U`.

**Update2**: If the OP is trying to differentiate between "normal English" strings and "Unicode Strings", the above approach will not work, because all characters have a corresponding Unicode representation.

However, one heuristic you might use to check whether a string looks like ASCII is to just check whether the values of each character are outside the normal ASCII range. Assuming that you consider the normal ASCII range to be between `32` and `127` (You can take a look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) and decide what you want to include.), you can do something like the following.

```
def isNormal(myStr):
    myChars = [ord(x) for x in myStr]
    return all(x < 128 and x > 31 for x in myChars)
```

This can be done in one line, but I separated it to make it more readable.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I convert `myStr` to something with real `\U`? I only have access to `myStr` and not to the `'\U0001f64c\U0001f60d\U0001f4a6\U0001f445\U0001f4af'`.

Comment: @TJ1, That is an interesting question which I will look into. :)

Comment: @TJ1, See my update. I also tried your proposal, but it still shows `False` on Python 3.3.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution as well, so I up voted it :-)